# Python: Remove text between <Table></Table> from text

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am still relatively new to the use of `regex` in Python and I am struggling to find a way to remove the content between the tags  in a very simple .txt file. See this [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tnpm55xe1ovh7ow/0001047469-98-044981.txt?dl=0) for example.

Here's what I've tried:

```
fdir = open("C:\\file.txt")
line = fdir.read()
line = line.lower()
pattern = re.compile("(?is)<table[^>]*>(.*?)<\/table>", re.MULTILINE)
line = pattern.sub('', line)
```

and

```
fdir = open("C:\\file.txt")
line = fdir.read()
line = re.sub(r"(?is)<table[^>]*>(.*?)<\/table>", '', line, re.DOTALL)
```

Both codes simply remove the tags `<Table>` and `<\Table>` in my text file and not what is in between. What's missing in my code? **I want the tags to be deleted as well.**

Comment: The tags should get remove as well. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: It works for me.you don't need to add `re.DOTALL` if `(?s)` is already included in your regex.

Comment: The usual sermon applies. Don't use regular expressions on HTML. **Regular expressions are technically incapable of handling HTML.** Use [a parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). Python even makes it ridiculously easy.

Comment: @Tomalak: True enough, although for parsing HTML with a fixed, simple format that's _guaranteed_ not to change, regexes may be adequate. FWIW, according to the lxml docs, Beautiful Soup uses regexes internally. OTOH, I suppose it's a Bad Idea to appear to be endorsing the use of regexes to parse HTML.

Comment: @PM2Ring **A)** Why would you want to turn down a tool that is as safe (and simple to use) as BeautifulSoup for a tool that is several orders of magnitude less maintainable, only works against a narrow and fixed set of inputs and breaks silently for unanticipated inputs? **B)** *All* parsers use regexes internally. That's not even close to a valid argument. **C)** Yes, telling people that don't know a whole lot about regexes how they could use them on HTML is a bad thing. Because then these people begin to think they can use regexes on HTML.

Comment: @Tomalak **A)** They may only _need_ to parse a narrow and fixed set of inputs, so they don't care if it fails outside that use case. And they want a simple script that doesn't require installation of 3rd party modules. **B)** I'm not sure if all parsers use regexes internally; I got the impression that lxml generally doesn't, except for when a user explicitly wants regex handling via EXSLT, or when lxml hands off parsing to BeautifulSoup. **C)** I think we both agree on this point.

Comment: @Tomalak: It's pretty obvious from many questions here that plenty of people get into difficulties using regex on HTML. Generally, either their regex skills are inadequate, or the HTML is not sufficiently narrow and fixed to be suitable for regex parsing. Maybe they don't want to invest the time required to learn how to use a proper HTML parser, and they use regex because they already know it (or think they do). OTOH, it doesn't take that long to learn the basics of Beautiful Soup. I guess it takes a bit longer to master lxml, but I think the increased power is well worth the effort.

Comment: @PM2Ring **A)** I understand, but this is is wishful thinking. The OP did not specify what their inputs look like, so assuming they might be well-defined, narrow and never invalid so you can justify the use of regex results in bad advice (also for the people that arrive here through Google). **B)** It was an over-generalization. Regex is a good fit for parsing out an HTML attribute value, a tag name or a CDATA section for example. Regex just can't handle the *whole of HTML* at the same time. Important distinction.

Comment: @PM2Ring There is always some sort of laziness ("Eww, I don't want to learn a new tool!") and misguided confidence ("Boy regex look complex, they can do *anything*, I'm just not quite at the sweet spot yet!"). I think it's important to point out that this particular kind of laziness is not a trait and that this confidence is unjustified. (That's what led to my "don't endorse..." comment below. There are *way* too many people on the web doing that already.) Funny thing: The more a person learns about regular expressions, the more they understand that using them on HTML is bad and wrong.

Comment: @Tomalak: And the more a person attempts to use regex on fancy HTML the more pain they experience; eventually, some of us learn not to do it. :) I must confess I've used regex to parse limited HTML myself. And I sometimes help fix regexes in HTMl + regex questions here, but I almost always tell the OP that regex + HTML is not a good strategy and they should consider using a proper parser. But I'll try to be more diligent in promoting the use of proper parsers in future.

Comment: @PM2Ring Cool. :) That being said, there isn't a web developer in the world who hasn't used regexes on HTML. Sometimes it's even unavoidable (think text editors). It's an ironic situation: As long as you have to ask somebody how to solve an HTML problem with regular expressions, you don't know enough about them and shouldn't be "allowed" to do it. As soon as you know enough about them, you don't actually want to do it anymore. (Corollary, close to 100% of regex-html questions here on SO *should* provoke a "don't" answer, along with a pointer to a proper parser.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to remove these tags ...

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> for t in soup.find_all('table'):
...     t.decompose()
```

Comment: ahhh nice! that does it!

Answer (score 1):

Use *[re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)*:

```
line = re.sub("(?is)<table[^>]*>(.*?)<\/table>", "", line)
```

I agree with Tomalak (see comments below): [HTML shouldn't be parsed using regex](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) - this answer is for demonstration only and shouldn't be used in production code.

Comment: Please don't recommend regular expressions for HTML questions.

Comment: @Tomalak I didn't recommend regex for HTML questions.

Comment: That's hairsplitting. Your answer endorses using regular expressions for working on HTML. And with 20+k rep you should know better.

Comment: Just to add the real-world case that can easily happen and breaks this code: Nested tables.